# Javassist no such field when variable clearly exists

Tags: java, code-injection, javassist

I am trying to inject code into the minecraft 1.8 jar using javassist. The `insertBefore` & `insertAfter` methods work perfectly fine. But the insert at method does not work as expected. I am getting this error:
https://gist.github.com/czaarek99/dda36426318f331ce6b0

Here is the code that handles the injection:

```
if (className.equals(mappingManager.getMapping(CommonMappings.MINECRAFT_CLASS))) {

    CtClass ctClass = classPool.get(mappingManager.getMapping(CommonMappings.MINECRAFT_CLASS, true)); //returns "bsu"

    CtMethod tickMethod = ctClass.getDeclaredMethod(mappingManager.getMapping(CommonMappings.RUN_TICK_METHOD)); //returns "r"
    tickMethod.insertBefore("EventManager.call(new TickEvent(TickEvent.PRE_UPDATE));");
    tickMethod.insertAfter("EventManager.call(new TickEvent(TickEvent.POST_UPDATE));");

    String varName = mappingManager.getMapping(CommonMappings.KEYBOARD_KEYCODE_VARIABLE); //returns "var1"

    int lineToInsertAt = Integer.valueOf(mappingManager.getMapping(CommonMappings.KEYBOARD_NEXT_LINE)); //returns "1372"
    tickMethod.insertAt(lineToInsertAt, true, "KeyPressEvent keyPressEvent = new KeyPressEvent("+ varName +");EventManager.call(keyPressEvent);");;

    CtMethod runGameMethod = ctClass.getDeclaredMethod(mappingManager.getMapping(CommonMappings.START_GAME_METHOD)); //returns "aj"
    runGameMethod.insertAfter("InjectClient.getInstance().loadModules();");

    byte[] newCode = ctClass.toBytecode(); //line that throws the error
    ctClass.detach();

    return newCode;
}
```

I have commented the lines where it grabs a mapping, essentially these are minecraft obfuscated variable & function names since this is what I will be inserting to.

Alright, so the logical explanation is that `var1` does not exist? That's not true. If we have a look at the code for the obfuscated `bsu` class we can see this:
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't IntelliJ color `var1` in purple if it was an attribute ? It looks like a local variable to me

Comment: @Dici It is a local variable defined a few lines above? And don't look at the colors, intellij doesn't color right when you decompile. This is a decompiled version of the class. EDIT: Just realized I named the question "field" let me change that

Comment: No, don't change that. The error message mentions a field... If it is a local variable, then you may be using it as a field somewhere else, which explains your bug

Comment: @Dici Hmmm, so it seems like javasist thinks that the `var1` variable is a field instead of a loca variable I guess.

Comment: I don't understand your code in depth, but I think you are using `var1` in a place where it is out of scope, then it can only be considered as a field, which does not exist, hence the error

Comment: @Dici Clearly that is not the case? You see `var1 = ...` on line 1369, I am injecting my code on line 1372. How would var1 be out of scope there?

Comment: In particular, I don't understand how the `mappingManager` works. How is it able to return you what you ask for, and what is the type of the constants defined on `CommonsMapping` ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright I figured it out. Turns out javassist does not know if a local variable is defined and it assumed `var1` was a field. I solved it by just creating  my own variable and setting the it to the same value as `var1` has.

Source: http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html

Comment: Sounds like a hack. Usually it is better to understand why something happened instead of finding a weird workaround and move forward

Comment: @Dici I'd say its more of limitation of javassist? I checked around the API and couldn't find a way to get the variable. If someone has a better solution then they can go ahead.

Comment: @Dici Yeah turns out my assumption was right [source](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-dyn0916/)

Comment: Hummm yeah, seems so. Good job :) +1