# javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such field: $1

Tags: java, code-injection, bytecode, instrumentation, javassist

Referring to : http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html

```
method.insertBefore("{ System.out.println($1);}");
```

This statement gives me following error:

```
Exception: javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such field: $1
javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] no such field: $1
        at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:774)
        at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:734)
        at com.here.debugHelper.DurationTransformer.transform(DurationTransformer.java:124)
        at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(Unknown Source)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at com.here.debugHelper.TestInstrumentation.main(TestInstrumentation.java:10)
Caused by: compile error: no such field: $1
        at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.fieldAccess(TypeChecker.java:845)
        at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atFieldRead(TypeChecker.java:803)
        at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMember(TypeChecker.java:988)
        at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atMember(JvstTypeChecker.java:66)
        at javassist.compiler.ast.Member.accept(Member.java:39)
        at javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atMethodArgs(JvstTypeChecker.java:221)
        at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atMethodCallCore(TypeChecker.java:735)
        at javassist.compiler.TypeChecker.atCallExpr(TypeChecker.java:695)
        at   javassist.compiler.JvstTypeChecker.atCallExpr(JvstTypeChecker.java:157)
        at javassist.compiler.ast.CallExpr.accept(CallExpr.java:46)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.doTypeCheck(CodeGen.java:242)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:330)
        at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
        at javassist.compiler.CodeGen.atStmnt(CodeGen.java:351)
        at javassist.compiler.ast.Stmnt.accept(Stmnt.java:50)
        at javassist.compiler.Javac.compileStmnt(Javac.java:567)
        at javassist.CtBehavior.insertBefore(CtBehavior.java:754)
        ... 17 more
```

Moreover,the same error appears when I use any parameter(passed to the parameter) or any local variable instead of '$1'. This has been covered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423185/javassist-no-such-field-when-variable-clearly-exists) question, but I don't really understand the solution there.

There is [this](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/93903) other post with same question but no answer.

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Alright, this is how I worked around the problem. There were few mistakes that  I was overlooking and some things that I learnt. I am sharing this since I could not find the content directly addressing the issue anywhere.
Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423185/javassist-no-such-field-when-variable-clearly-exists) answer and [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-dyn0916/) article:

The `insertBefore`, `insertAfter` and *other such methods* **cannot access any local variable but can access method parameter of the method** by their names. `no such field` error occurs if attempt is made to access local variable.

These methods cannot access any parameter declared within them as a process of instrumentation.
`ctmethod.insertBefore("{int i = 4; int j = 9;}")
ctmethod.insertBefore("i = 5;");
ctMethod.insertAfter("j = 9;");`

- The above code will give `no such field: j(and i)` error
- `insertBefore`, `insertAfter`, expect a single statement, or a single block of code as done in first line of above code snippet.
- This error `no such field` appears in case when variables are used in `ctmethod.addcatch()` too.
- `ctmethod.addLocalVariable()` helps in declaring a variable that can be accessed by `insertBefore()`, etc. However, `.addCatch()` will still give `no such field` error if you try to use variable declared using `.addLocalVariable()`
- I was getting `no such field: $1` due to my silly mistake. I was going iterating through a number of method in a class, so the error was due to the fact that some of those methods had **zero arguments**. `$1,$2.. and $args` work well as explained in [this](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html) doc.

P.S. I will add further tips as I come across them and any corrections are welcomed.